# Is there a pre-built "push" iOS developer app in the app-store?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I'm building a server-side "push" notification capability for various (specific) iOS apps my company makes.  I'm not a mobile developer.  I understand there's a "p12" certificate I'd need, and that the mobile client must provide the "token" I use to initiate the push from the server.

Does anyone know if there's a pre-built developer/test iOS app in the store that will display a token, has a downloadable cert, etc., and will accept push notifications?  I'd like to build the server-side out a bit before I try to plug in the real tokens/certs for my companies apps.

Comment: you just need pem file both for production and development being different

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, but there are 2 separated environments one for test and one for production. 
Usually the app developer team should provide the certificates to the back end developer team. 
Once you have your certificates you can integrate them in the backend.
Pay attention that certificates are app specific, they work only for a given identifier.
During test both the team should work together to see if everything work as expected.
Token can be track in a different way, in debug mode using real device by printing them in the console log or by using a particular configuration file, in both cases the device must be connected to Xcode.
You should ask the dev team if they can provide you a sample app that print the token on the device screen and  that just send the token to the server to make your experiments.